# Incapsula And Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, incapsula

## Incapsula and Websocket

I have a problem about my websocket connection. My english is not so good but i will try to tell my problem clearly.

We have console websocket application which uses 3131 as a port on server. It was working fine until we enabled incapsula protection. They said incapsula is working websockets fine but im getting "error time out" when i tried to connect websocket right now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from the Imperva Incapsula team.
I believe the problem is with port 3131, try using a different port (8082 should work).

If the problem persists, please open a ticket and our support stuff will gladly help you.

Best,
Ofer

Comment: Yea its really about the port number. I changed to 8082 and it worked like magic. Thank you so much.